# HttpClient problems with API: Error Code 404

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm having difficulty calling an API through an Android app. 
I was using this website for help: http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON

When I try to change the URL to the API that I want to use, I'm get getting  a: "Server responded with status code: 404".

This is my first time using AsyncTask so I hope I'm doing it correctly. Here is my AsyncTask class:

```
private class PostFetcher extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private static final String TAG = "PostFetcher";
    public String SERVER_URL = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            //Create an HTTP client
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);

            //Perform the request and check the status code
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();

                try {
                    //Read the server response and attempt to parse it as JSON
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);

                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected");

                    content.close();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON due to: " + ex);
                    failedLoadingPosts();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server responded with status code: " + statusLine.getStatusCode());
                failedLoadingPosts();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: " + ex);
            failedLoadingPosts();
        }
        return null;
    } 
}
```

And on onCreate, I call: 
PostFetcher fetcher = new PostFetcher();
fetcher.execute();

Any ideas as to why I'm getting a 404 error code, even though the website is functional? Thanks!

Comment: Also PLEASE consume your httpentity. MALLOC will not collect it !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to use HTTP GET in place of POST.

Comment: Ugh! How can something so simple give such a huge headache!? Thanks! It was able to go through.

Answer (score 0):

Are you set permission

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

?

and try this way

```
class PostFetcher extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private static final String TAG = "PostFetcher";
public String SERVER_URL = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        String result ="";

        URL myUrl = new URL(SERVER_URL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                .openConnection();

        //conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); //if you need set POST
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.connect();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String lineJSON = null;
        while ((lineJSON = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(lineJSON + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, result);


    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: " + ex);
        //failedLoadingPosts();
    }
    return null;
} 
}
```

good luck!